# DirectoryInfo GetFiles TOP number

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo

I want to return 10 files only from a directory. Is this possible?

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/xml"));

FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.xml");
```

This way returns *all* XML files, but I want to get just the first ten.

Comment: Usage of GetFiles().Take(10) is as slow (and memory-wise) as GetFile(). Use .Net 4.0's EnumerateFiles() to save time and memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the extension method Take(10) to only grab the first 10 files.

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/xml"));
var files = d.GetFiles("*.xml").OrderByDescending(fi=>fi.LastWriteTime).Take(10);
```

Comment: very nice. I will put correct. How can I order by changed date?

Comment: @Jake Small mistake: Take returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` and you assign it to a `FileInfo[]`

Comment: @Beginner you can do  d.GetFiles().Take(3).OrderBy( r => r.CreationTime).ToArray(); for orderBy

Comment: @Beginner Put `.OrderBy(fi=>fi.LastWriteTime)` or `.OrderByDescending(fi=>fi.LastWriteTime)` before the `.Take(10)`. Assuming you want the 10 most recently changed files and not 10 random files you need to sort first and then limit the number with take. So not what @anish recommended

Comment: SHOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW .OrderByDescending(fi=>fi.LastWriteTime)

Answer (score 12):

If you're using .NET4 then you should probably use [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead, along with the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) extension method:

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/xml"));
FileInfo[] files = d.EnumerateFiles("*.xml").Take(10).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. The solution by Jake Pearson currently marked as correct uses GetFiles which returns an array type which means ALL the files will be materialised before you can apply the LINQ statement Take.
Using EnumerateFiles returns an IEnumerable which will only walk the amount of files applied by the Take... LINQ can be so dangerous if you don't watch the return types and note how they behave :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to the same what Jake mentioned, but  not `FileInfo[] files`

```
      DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("~/xml");
      IEnumerable< FileInfo> files = d.GetFiles().Take(10);

                         OR

     DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("~/xml");
      FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles().Take(10).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Tab16_mainPath);


  var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles().Take(3)
                orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                select f).ToArray();
```